# Pandas series.notna() returning true to series containing NaNs

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which I am subsetting to create a series and then searhc if that series contains any nans before executing code. But I am getting series with NaNs being passed to the subsequent code.

Example of dataframe:

```
   sample classification          type  similar  ...  respiraroty activity antimicrobial molecular details               Litrature
7     M41      predicted       melanin  melanin  ...                   NaN           NaN               NaN  10.1073/pnas.211433198
17    RB1      predicted       melanin  melanin  ...                   NaN           NaN               NaN  10.1073/pnas.211433198
21    RB1      predicted       melanin  melanin  ...                   NaN           NaN               NaN  10.1073/pnas.211433198
32   RB17      predicted  NRPS,melanin  melanin  ...                   NaN           NaN               NaN  10.1073/pnas.211433198
```

I am subsetting the dataframe by the `similar` column then checking if the `description` column contains any `NaNs`

```
    for compound in compound_list:
        subset_compound = antismash.loc[antismash['similar'] == compound]
        if subset_compound['Description'].notna().any():
            print(subset_compound['Description'])
# just one output example
    3                                       NaN
    12                                      NaN
    25                                      NaN
    33                                      NaN
    43                                      NaN
    49                                      NaN
    51                                      NaN
    54                                      NaN
    76                                      NaN
    82     aids in osmotic stress survivability
    84                                      NaN
    90                                      NaN
    94                                      NaN
    97                                      NaN
    100                                     NaN
    106                                     NaN
    119    aids in osmotic stress survivability
    129                                     NaN
```

When cheking boolean response to `notna()`:

```
        print(subset_compound['Description'].notna().any())
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
```

The if statment is letting through dataframes with NaNs in the `Description`column. If I understand the `subset_compound['Description']` outputs a pandas series. What is causing `notna()`to not see the `NaNs`inside the series?

Comment: It is the `.any()` why everything is returning `True` As long as one element in the series (along the same axis) is true all will return true

Comment: Hmm maybe. I am not really sure of the other options I can use. Is there documentation on them anywhere?

Comment: Here is the [any()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) documentation.

Comment: Why don't you use Pandas Series.isnull() function?

Comment: Looks like df.notna() applie to DF so when you use any() with it, it may not work. Also note that, characters such as empty strings '' or numpy.inf are not considered NA values (unless you set pandas.options.mode.use_inf_as_na = True). NA values, such as None or numpy.NaN, get mapped to False values.

Comment: I am using `series.notna` and it is working just not as I expect. I am pretty sure they are `NaN` values, but do you know of a way to check what type of `NaN` they are?

Comment: @Chris It seems `all()` produces the expected behaviour but I am not really sure why. The options I have are to use any one of `a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()` but I don't fully understand their uses.

Comment: if you used `print(subset_compound['Description'].notna().any())` in the for loop that would explain the multiple `True` outputs... `.any()` should only give you one single boolean.

I think what you really are looking for is [df.dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. pandas.notna(obj): Detect non-missing values for an array-like object.

   ```
   array = np.array([[1, np.nan, 3], [4, 5, np.nan]])
   pd.notna(array)
   // array([[ True, False,  True], [ True,  True, False]])
   ```
2. DataFrame.any(): Return whether any element is True, potentially over an axis.

   ```
   pd.Series([False, False]).any()
   // False
   pd.Series([True, False]).any()
   // True
   ```

Problem in your code is notna() return True if your numpy array contains any value different from NaN. And then any() return True if there is any True value inside the result came from notna(). At the end of the they your code checks "Is there any value different from NaN". To solve this problem in your code:

```
for compound in compound_list:
    subset_compound = antismash.loc[antismash['similar'] == compound]
    if subset_compound['Description'].isna().any():
        print(subset_compound['Description'])
```

Answer (score 0):

`df[col].notna().any()` is True if the column has any values that are not NaN. It will only be False if every value in the column is NaN.

```
=== Executing: ===

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(5), 'b': [np.nan for _ in range(5)]})                                                    

print(df1['a'].notna().any(), df1['b'].notna().any())

=== Output: ===

True False
```

Comment: Using àll()` seems to produce the expected behaviour but I don't know if it is the correct truth value to use ?